# TensorFlow Object detection RMSProp vs. Adam

Tags: tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, object-detection

Does anyone know why the tensorflow object detection SSD config sample files use `rms_prop_optimizer` instead of `adam_optimizer`? Is there a performance benefit to doing that for this model?

Comment: Love downvotes without comments..

Comment: I really don't understand the down-vote. I'm voting this up since it is a legitimate question. Any information about this I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think there is any specific reason, it just that adam is a better version of rmsprop. [This](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#rmsprop) can help.